# How to extend grails domain class without having extended class mapped to database?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I am trying to extend the domain classes in our grails application so that they can all use a common method.  This however is erroring out on me, it seems that grails is trying to map the extended class to the database. Does anyone know how to do this?

I have tried the following:

- Making the extended class abstract
- Moving the extended class to the src/groovy folder
- Adding "tablePerHierarchy false" to the extending class' static mapping

Unfortunately all of these fail.  Note that it works fine if I do not extend at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering it seems you have to do a combination of what I tried.
You need to both make the extended class abstract and place it in the src/groovy folder.
Hope this helps someone!